# .net installer to add mysql database tables on install

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, installation

I am getting to a point now with my program where by i am writing the .net installer to install it in the right location etc.

my question is, is there a way that when i run the installer i can also add database tables to a mysql database?

or should i write a seperate program to run after install which checks the db and adds the tables if nessary?

once again any help is appreciated

Vades

Comment: Are you writing your own installer or are you utilizing the msi?

Comment: using the one in vs2008 so utilizing the msi i guess :)

Comment: Vade - did my answer give You any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the Installer Class to add Custom installer actions

[Installer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx)

Just add it to your primary output and add its primaryoutput to custom action "on install"

[Step by step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28VS.80%29.aspx)